# jQuery PLUpload How to get renamed filename?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, plupload

I'm have already implemented the PLUpload Html5 plugin to my codeigniter. I am able to get the upload working but unable to get the updated renamed filename.

I did a print_r($this->input->post()) and it returns one of the fields as [update_0_name] test-file-name.png. The actual filename that was rename was test_file_name.png or even test_filne_name_1.png if there's duplicate file.

So how can I get the updated filename?

I was curious as to why the dump.php is able to get the updated filename while I can't. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Can you dump the results of `print_r($this->input->post())`?

Comment: Array ( [title] => Title Testing [folder_id] => 2 [uploader_0_name] => pic_day.jpg [uploader_0_status] => done [uploader_count] => 1 )

The actual filename is pic_day_1.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somehow, I managed to find an answer in StackOverFlow.

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, info) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(info.response);
    $('form#form-files-uploader').append('<input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="' + obj.cleanFileName + '" />');
});
```

It works for me. Please advise if this is correct way even though it's working. Thanks.

Comment: if it worked for you then mark your answer as correct. Not sure what you are looking for. `file.name` is the real file name and `file.id` is the unique id pluplaoder gave it.